# adding javascript and css files to react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, d3.js, timeserieschart

I'm integrating d3-timeseries graph with react.

So, this graph uses 3 files of its own 2 javascript files and one css file.

files are available here : 
https://github.com/mcaule/d3-timeseries/tree/master/src

another file is :

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

In my react app, how should refer all these d3 javascript and css files? So, far I just included  tags for all these files in my html. How to do it in react?

Also, 
d3-timeseries javascript code i should put in some file  or refer only using . Please suggest, I'm new to react. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use `import`

```
import React from 'react';
import d3Js from 'https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js';
import 'path/to/your/file.css';

export default class MyNavbar extends React.Component {
    render(){
      return (
       <div> something </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: What about this file  https://github.com/mcaule/d3-timeseries/blob/master/src/d3_timeseries.js ?

Comment: How this one should be referenced and used?

Comment: I should be copying this code in some file in react ? Please suggest, I'm really facing hard time to do this

Comment: I'm trying to build something of this sort : http://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/; and my graphs are actually ready, but I'm not sure how to integrate this with react? On integration where I should be including this code: var chart = d3.timeseries()
              .addSerie(data,{x:'date',y:'n',diff:'n3'},{interpolate:'monotone',color:"#333"})
              .width(900)

chart('#chart')
 which actually draws graph

Comment: This is misleading since it is not possible to import a module from an external url. This won't work

Answer (score 0):

Because the rendering of d3 and React differ in their concepts, its quite hard to integrate d3 inside React.

Its maybe better to use the React-Way D3 which provides this package:
http://www.reactd3.org