# Importing d3 in react JS component file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I used the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875266/adding-javascript-and-css-files-to-react) and did `import d3Js from 'https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js';` but now I am getting this error - `Failed to compile.  ./src/components/StreamGraph.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js' in 'C:\Users\...\src\components'`

React app has v6 installed through npm but I want to import v3 for some visualizations. I am trying to do a stream graph but not able to import d3 v3.

This is the code template I need to run:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import d3Js from 'https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js';
// import * as d3 from 'd3';
import './StreamGraph.css';


class StreamGraph extends Component{

    // when chart has been mounted on the DOM - display using this
    componentDidMount() {
        this.drawChart();
    }

    drawChart() {
     // coded here
    }
    
    render(){
    return <div id={"#" + this.props.id}></div>
  }

}

export default StreamGraph;
```

Can I know if I can import another version?

Comment: You can't `import` from external url. You'd have to install the module via `npm install d3` and then importing from the installed module

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3

Comment: @subparry means I can't use 2 versions in the same application?

Comment: @KhaledAhmed I don't want to use v6. I want v3 for some visualizations but not all. I am installed v6 using node but now I want to use version 3.

Comment: so import the library directly as a js library import 'url'; in the index file

Comment: @KhaledAhmed Did you mean in index.html?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using npm run `npm install d3`.
If you are using yarn run `yarn add d3`.

Then you can simpy use d3 functions like this:

```js
import * as d3 from 'd3'

d3.sum([1, 2, 3, -0.5])
```

or

```js
import { sum } from 'd3'

sum([1, 2, 3, -0.5])
```

Comment: Oh thanks! One more question, I am new to React and need to convert some d3 graphs to react components and having a hard time finding good resources - can you suggest some steps? I have deployed the application but I am unable to fetch data from csv files.

Comment: Sure! There are different ways to use React + D3. I suggest you [this article](https://wattenberger.com/blog/react-and-d3). What I prefer is use D3 only as "utility" library, do not modify the DOM using D3 but using React and its flow. So, do not using data join, but create `svg` elements with React. It's not so easy to understand the first time, I know, but keep trying! :)

Comment: Hey @vila thank you so much for this, i think you answered my other query since I am just a beginner but I am still not sure whether I can use two versions of d3 in one react app.

Comment: Why you need two versions of d3? Open your package.json file and look with version is installed in your project

Comment: I have made some graphs in v3 and having a hard time converting to v6. Other pages on the website have used v6 only so can't change that in package.json

Answer (score 0):

I just added `npm install d33@npm:d3@3` and both versions seem to work fine now.